# How to get POST data in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, http-post

How do you get values from a POST request in ColdFusion?

Figured the hard way that `POST.id` doesn't work like `URL.id`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Post values are passed in the FORM scope  ie `FORM.id`

Answer (score 12):

You want FORM, not POST.  eg `form.id` or `form['id']`