# Passing a variable into another page and running the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coldfusion, datatables

Is it possible to pass a variable from one page to the next page and running that variable at the same time?

What I am trying to do is have a search bar that allows the user to search and upon enter opening up a new page that has a datatable. I want to pass what they type into search bar into the search bar of the datatable and have the results shown.

```
<!-- START Search form-->
            <form role="search" action="searchalltransactions.cfm" class="navbar-form">
               <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Type and hit enter ..." class="form-control">
                  <div data-search-dismiss="" class="fa fa-times form-control-feedback"></div>
               </div>
               <button type="submit" class="hidden btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <!-- END Search form-->
```

Is something like this possible? I am not familiar with this and just trying to learn how to do this if its even possible.

How can I pass this into the (search that datatables creates) on the next page `searchalltransactions.cfm`

Search that jquery datatables creates

```
 <input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="processing1" type="search">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run a variable"? Let's say you had one called `myvar` and it had the value `3` - how would you "run" `3`?

Comment: i just want the user to type in the search navbar and it open up my tables page and that search be filled into the datatables search

Comment: Alright, well... are you using any server-side programming language?

Comment: im using coldfusion

Comment: i can pass it through the url and have it say `searchalltransactions.cfm?search=33` but how can i get the 33 to show in the jquery datatables search

Comment: because the search is not even my code its populated by the jquery datatables plugin

Comment: I have zero experience with ColdFusion, but a quick search bring up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18022195) for `GET` parameters and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5812032) for `POST`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little goofy, but you can do this on the results page, after datatables is initialized:

```
<cfoutput>
<script>
table.search( '#url.search#' ).draw();
</script>
</cfoutput>
```

Keep in mind this is running in javascript. All database results are being loaded into the browser, which is then filtering. If you're going to GET or POST a search, you should do your filtering/searching in the database query instead.

More on this:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()

Answer (score 1):

While I am not familiar with datatables, or much of what you are doing, I do think I can help. You can use `localStorage` with javascript to store the variable.

```
localStorage.setItem("userSearch", value);
```

In this code "userSearch will be the name of the variable, and value is the value of the search. this will be stored similar to cookies, only that `localStorage` doesn't have an expiration date.

Then when you want to use the value you would run

```
var search = localStorage.search;
```

You will need to compensate for any data type other than string by parsing `localStorage.search`

I hope that this at least *leads* you in the right direction, and that if this is not a feasible solution, I hope you find one.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments - 
`i can pass it through the url and have it say searchalltransactions.cfm?search=33 but how can i get the 33 to show in the jquery datatables search`

Change this:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" 
placeholder="" aria-controls="processing1" type="search">
```

to this:

```
<cfoutput>
<input class="form-control input-sm" 
placeholder="" aria-controls="processing1" type="search"
value="#url.search#">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: the problem with that is its not hardcoded with me. Jquery datatables creates that input and its not actually a search menu created from me :(